# How does the type of syringe impact the number of doses of Corona vaccine available per vial?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, coronavirus

In an interview with Ron Klain (Biden's Chief of Staff) on CNN this morning, it was suggested that Biden would invoke the National Defense Production act to increase the production of syringes that would result in an ability to obtain 20% more doses from each vial of vaccine. [CNN at about 1:04 minute interview](https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2021/01/17/sotu-klain-vaccines.cnn)

I have not heard this previously reported, and I am unsure about the implications. (for example, does it imply that the use some syringes are wasting vaccine?)

Since the patient dose for the Pfizer vaccine is 0.3 cc (approximately 6 drops), I would have thought that the preferred syringe capacity would be 0.5 or 1cc.

**What are the scientific basis about this proposal (that would lead to a to recommendation to use particular types of syringes),  and is the rationale well reasoned?**

Comment: [Recent link](https://in.news.yahoo.com/biden-unveil-coronavirus-vaccine-distribution-070812550.html) (syringes **and other supplies**) and [CNBC Dec 28, 2020](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/12/28/biden-will-invoke-defense-production-act-to-boost-covid-vaccine-production-advisor-says.html) (boost Covid vaccine production)

Comment: @ChrisRogers neither citation addresses the production of **certain** syringes that would/could increase the number of doses per vial.

Comment: That was the point I was making indirectly, although the articles mentioned using the National Defense Production Act to increase vaccine provision. +1 from me now you have found a link to the interview and provided it

Comment: From personal experience in a biological laboratory, a) all syringes have dead space, b) the amount of dead space is highly variable. I'd say it passes an obvious smell test but beyond that I doubt you will find much. As far as "details of this proposal" I don't see any relevance to medical sciences for that bit.

Comment: @BryanKrause The details I'm seeking are the **scientific** details of medical syringes relative to efficiency of use that would form the basis to recommend particular types syringes for administration of a 'in-short-supply' vaccine.   I would anticipate  these "details" (best syringes to use) to have come from a medical advisory team to the President-elect.

Comment: @BryanKrause   From my personal experience, I know that delivery accuracy of a injectable is related to the size of the syringe. To accurately deliver 1 cc, personally I would not use a 10 cc or larger capacity syringe (the same might be said of using graduated pipettes). While this has been **my** experience, what I'm trying to understand is that the rationale behind advising the president-elect.

Answer (score 1):

Found this that appears to answer the question of the differences between two types of syringes.
Apparently the mean loss difference is 0.082 ml. Over the course of 5 inoculations (using a new syringe each time) a total of 0.41 ml would be conserved using the low dead-space syringe. Since the dosage per patient is 0.3,  ml, theoretically 1 more inoculation can be obtained when using low dead space syringes. (20% increase). This is in agreement with what Ron Klain was saying.

Going beyond that however it also appears that 7 doses per vial is feasible (which would represent a 40% increase in the number of innoculations per vial.

The Pfizer vaccine vial is prefilled with 0.45 ml, and to that the clinician is to add 1.80 ml, so that the total volume per vial is 2.250 ml.

If using a "high" dead space syringe, drawn to .3 ml, the total withdrawn from the vial is 0.382 ml per dose. With the vial volume at 2.250 ml, only 5 complete doses can be withdrawn

OTOH, if using the "low" dead space syringe, drawn to 0.3 ml, the total withdrawn from the vial is 0.302 ml per dose.  With the vial volume at 2.250 ml, 7 complete doses can be withdrawn.

7 doses per vial versus 5 is a 40% increase.

What I was hoping to see was that the WH COVID19 scientists were making and publishing similar calculations.

[image: Wikipedia image comparing syringes]

Comment: Like I said in a comment, syringes have variable amounts of dead space. Nothing shocking about that. This doesn't seem to answer your own question with the level of detail you were originally asking for, though.